# Changing an image src via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id = "current">
  <img src = "dog.jpg">
</div>
```

My attempt to change dog to dog-small.jpg

```
$("#left").click(function(){
    var $current = $("#current");
    $current.children('img').attr('src').replace('.','-small.');
    console.log($current.children('img').attr('src').replace('.','-small.'));
});
```

console prints : dog-small.jpg -> correct
however the image does not change on the page, and when I inspect the element its src remains to be dog-small.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with an example solution https://jsfiddle.net/2xacp15m/1/

```js
var updatedSRC = "small-dog.jpg";

$('button').click(function(){
 console.log("Old: " +  $('#current').find('img').attr('src'));
   $('#current').find('img').attr('src', updatedSRC);
   
   console.log("Updated: " +  $('#current').find('img').attr('src'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "current">
  <img src = "dog.jpg">
</div>

<button type="submit">
  Submit
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the new src as the second parameter to .attr()

```
$("#left").click(function(){
    var $current = $("#current");
    var newSrc = $current.children('img').attr('src').replace('.','-small.');
    $current.children('img').attr('src', newSrc);
    console.log($current.children('img').attr('src'));
});
```